# Error deploy with Firebase: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Tags: firebase

Used to deploy all the time no problem.
Now doing the exact same thing, with some changes to the source code, and I get this on the terminal every time :

```
getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND servicemanagement.googleapis.com servicemanagement.googleapis.com:443
```

*I read here* a few answers about anti-virus(I don't have), and errors in code (I don't see something new on the console).

What else can I check ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by `auth` again, which redirect to a browser and login into my *right* email address :

Run this :  `firebase login --reauth`